# ReactJS & Visual Studio 2015 - exclude generated files

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, reactjs

I'm using VS2015 for a ReactJS front end. I created the project using the React template in VS.

I have got a couple of questions regarding the setup:

- How do I exclude the *.js files that are dynamically generated by transpiling the *.tsx files from VS (screenshot below)?
- Every time I make a change to the code in a *.tsx file, I'm having to delete the previously generated *.js file and then run the webpack task from Task Runner Explorer window. Surely that's not right - what am I missing?

Thanks!

[image: VS screenshot with js files]